# How to install specific plugin in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, maven-install-plugin

`I want to install specific plugin of specific version in eclipse. Well, any version above a certain version (Ex: any version above 2.1.1)`
Is it possible to achieve this in eclipse? Is there a way to do this from command line? Like using **org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director** plugin? Also, downloading this plugin should download all its dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, see http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html for instructions. The -installIU parameter would just be the plug-in's ID and you will need to list the repository locations for all of its dependencies.

Comment: It would be better to add some simple example to your answer.

Comment: Here is what that helped me: proc=subprocess.Popen([eclipse_exe_location,'-application', 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director', '-repository', repository, '-installIU', 'pluginName']). Thanks!